# Cassandra invalid query "Map-entry equality predicates on frozen map column device_details are not supported"

Tags: cassandra

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dove.backend_events (
log_time_local timeuuid,
username text,
log_type text,
log_time timestamp,
device_category text,
log text,
device_details frozen<map<text, text>>,
PRIMARY KEY (log_time_local, username, device_details)
);
```

I am running this query: `SELECT * FROM dove.backend_events WHERE device_details['category'] = 'mobile' ALLOW FILTERING;`

I am getting this error: `InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Map-entry equality predicates on frozen map column device_details are not supported"`

What is causing it and how do I fix it? This error is not occurring when `device_details` is not part of the primary key and is not frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an index for `device_details` instead of setting it as primary key (and without freezing it):

```
CREATE TABLE dove.backend_events (
log_time_local timeuuid,
username text,
log_type text,
log_time timestamp,
device_category text,
log text,
device_details map<text, text>,
PRIMARY KEY (log_time_local, username)
);

CREATE INDEX dove.device_details_index ON dove.backend_events (ENTRIES(device_details));
```

This way you could run your query efficiently and without having to use `ALLOW FILTERING`:

```
SELECT * FROM dove.backend_events WHERE device_details['category'] = 'mobile';
```